# pointing to an element?

Tags: c, pointers

Edit. Would it be possible to take the second function and take as an argument a pointer to the element after the last element after the source? Example copy_ptrs (target3, source, source +5)

I included a copy of my entire program but what I am trying to do is use two functions, one using array notation and the other using pointer notation to simply copy the initial array elements read in by a user. My pointer function does not work however as it will not print the copy of the data. I think my pointer declarations are wrong? My knowledge of pointers is pretty limited but I think the solution is so close. Any help would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 999

void copy_arr(double ar[], double ar2[], int n);
void copy_ptr(double arr[], double arr2[], int n);

int main() 
{
    int i, num; 
    double source[MAX];
    double target1[MAX];
    double target2[MAX];


    printf("\nEnter number of elements to be read into the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("\nEnter the values below (press enter after each entry)\n");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    {
            scanf("%lf", &source[i]);
    }

    //copy_arr(target1, source, num);
    copy_ptr(target2, source, num);


    printf("\n\nCopying Complete!\n");

    return 0;
}

void copy_arr(double target1[], double source[], int num)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
    {
            target1[i] = source[i];
    }

    printf("\n***The first function uses array notation to copy the elements***\n");
    printf("===================================================================\n");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("\n              Array_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf", i, target1[i]);
    }

}
void copy_ptr(double target2[], double source[], int num)
{
    int i;
    double *p, *q;

    p = source;
    q = target2;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
            *q = *p;
        q++;
        p++;
    }
    q = target 2
    printf("\n\n***The second function uses pointer notation to copy the elements***\n");
    printf("===================================================================\n");

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
            printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf",i, *q++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `q` to print array `target2`. `q` is not pointing to it anymore at the end of `for` loop. Add this line before `printf`

```
    q = target2;
```

to reset pointer `q` to pint array `target2`.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed very close.

You just forgot to **reset `q` to `target2` before printing** ; so when printing you are trying to display elements past the end of the array.

For the "edit" part of your question, you can loop like this:

```
for (double *ptr = source ; ptr != pointer_after_last ; ++ptr)
```

Using this, you will have `ptr` pointing to each of the elements one after the other. If you want to keep track of the item number, just add a variable that you increase on each run of the loop.

The remainder of your program would be exactly the same.

Comment: can you take a look at my problem I am having again? I need to create another function but am stuck completely.

Answer (score 0):

In the second function (before you updated your post that should not be done; otherwise reades will be confused) you are trying to output elements of the destination array using already changed pointer in the preceding loop when the array was filled by elements of the source array

```
for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
        printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf",i, *q++);
                                                                      ^^^^^
}
```

Nevertheless in any case your function is incorrect rekative to the description of the assignment. You should not use a loop with an auxiliary count variable.

The correct function can look like

```
void copy_ptr( double target2[], const double source[], int num )
{
    const double *p = source;
    double *q = target2;

    for ( ; p != source + num; ++p, ++q )
    {
            *q = *p;
    }

    printf("\n\n***The second function uses pointer notation to copy the elements***\n");
    printf("===================================================================\n");

    int i = 0;
    for ( q = target2; q != target2 + num; ++q )
    {
            printf("\n              Pointer_Notation_Copy[%d] = %.2lf",i++, *q );
    }


}
```

Comment: You are missing to print the element number, since `i` is now undefined

Comment: @Gianluca  Thanks. I even did not see what is printed.:)